# How to set fix zoom level or scale back in webview?

Tags: android, webview, zooming

Zoom works without any problem, but if I select any input field the webview zooms in automatically.

How do I can prevent this zoom behavior?

- set fix zoom level?
- scale back to previous zoom level?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Android webkit, but this works on iOS webkit:

```
input[type='text'],textarea {font-size:1em;}
```